# Is it okay to ask question to which you know the answer but not sure of it?

Tags: discussion, support

There are certain concepts I think I know but I am not sure if that's the right way to understand it, so is it acceptable question on physics stack exchange. And how should that question be framed, should be it be sort of yes-no, or should it have an element of discussion?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1013/2451

Comment: Yes/No questions are bad because the answer (yes or no) is too short to be a valid answer; so you absolutely should have an element of discussion/explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to close this as a duplicate of that other one, particularly since the other talks about differences between beta (which the site was at the time) and grown up (which the site is now) and so further clarification is okay. Also, this question isn't "I know the answer so should I post," rather it is "I think I might know the answer but I am unsure, can I post a question to get clarification/discussion?"

Comment: But to expand on what Kyle said -- yes/no is bad, but so is "discussion," if by discussion you mean a back-and-forth conversation. So it would take some careful wording to make sure that it is answerable in a way that is useful to yourself and to others while still following the usual rules about question quality.

Comment: FWIW the post was closed as a duplicate by one close-vote from OP himself.